# gnuplot xtic labels mispositioning with dates

Tags: date, position, gnuplot

Normally don't have problem with setting x tics but this one's defying solution for me.

Plotting some values along a daily time series, so leading off with the commands

```
set xdata time  
set timefmt "%m/%d/%Y"  # the incoming dates are like 06/19/2016  
set format x "%b %Y"    # I want the tics to be like Jun 2016
```

I have an arrow as a marker in the plot

```
set arrow 1 from "10/15/2016", 0 to "10/15/2016", 4
```

...so I have a vertical line exactly on Oct 15 2016.

But with the command for my xtics...

```
set xtics "10/15/2016", 2628000
```

...I should have xtics beginning **on Oct 15** and occurring at roughly the 15th of each month. Problem is, the first xtic shows up about where **Oct 1st is, not the 15th**. Subsequently, the spacing is indeed about one month, but they're all near the first of each month, not the 15th.

The arrow is just to give me a visual marker on the date Oct 15, and its command uses the same format as the xtics command. After an hour of no luck with every configuration I can think of, it's time to go external for a fresh set of eyes.

Comment: interestingly, the tics seem to be as expected (gnuplot 5.0.5) when one uses `set xtics "10/15/2016", 3600*24*28-1`, but not with `3600*24*28` or more. Setting them manually with, e.g., `set xtics ("tick label" "10/16/2016" 0)` works though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in addition to the comment to the original question, the reason for this behavior seems to be that the function `setup_tics` in `src/axis.c` of the Gnuplot source tree sets (line 862) for values of the step larger than `3600*24*28` the timelevel of the corresponding major axis tics to `TIMELEVEL_MONTHS`.

However, as the comment in function `time_tic_just` on line 1351 of `src/axis.c` suggests (and code below confirms), the tic position is in this case indeed rounded to the first day of the month:

```
/* skip it, I have not bothered with weekday so far */
if (level >= TIMELEVEL_MONTHS) {/* units of month */
if (tm.tm_mday > 25) {
    tm.tm_mon++;
    if (tm.tm_mon > 11) {
    tm.tm_year++;
    tm.tm_mon = 0;
    }
}
tm.tm_mday = 1;
}
```